# Fetching a category and its sub/nested categories using Flexible Search

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I am trying to prepare a dynamic flexible query to fetch a category including its all sub/nested categories. Hybris keeps category relation in CategoryCategoryRelation and if I join the table itself it doesn't give a category if it doesn't have any subcategory.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your query here. Categorymodel already has a method `getAllSubcategories` which fetch all its subcategories. It's handled through dynamic attribute which internally calls `getAllSubcategoriesForCategory` method of `DefaultcategoryService`. Please check if you can use the same.